# No $key inside a AngularFireDatabase.object

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Angular app I am trying to update records on Firebase database. I am using **AngularFireDatabase** to first bind the list when then be used to update the particular records. But the problem is that there is no **$key**.

The app.component.html code is:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
    {{course}}
    <button (click)="update(course)">Update</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The app.component.ts is:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  courses: any[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.subscription = db.list('/couses').valueChanges().subscribe(c => {
      this.courses = c;
    });   
  }

  update(course) {
    console.log(course.$key);
    //gives key undefined
  }
}
```

How to get key so that I can update a particular record?

**The snapshot of firebase database is:**

[image]

Comment: show the `this.courses` array

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I have updated the question to include the snapshot of firebase db.

Comment: There is no property called `$key` in the dataset.

Comment: under the couses node on the database there are 1, 2, 3, I want to access them for updating records. How to achieve it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `.snapshotChanges()` method.

The constructor code becomes:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
this.subscription = db.list('/couses').snapshotChanges().subscribe(c => {
  this.courses = c;
});
```

The `update()` method:

```
update(course) {
this.db.list('/couses').set(course.key,"Updated");
```

}

So Now I am getting the key for doing update of the particular item.

I hope it help, if you have better solution then please have your answer.